# Android:Back to activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have activity a and b,
when I in activity b and preesed on the back key I back from activity b to activity a,
How do I make that when I back to activty a, activty a will be restart?

Comment: why do you want to restart your activity A?

Comment: You realize that if you do that you will end up creating a loop, right?

Answer (score 0):

**When your are launching activity B you should call finish() on activity A**

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this.,B.class)
 startActivity(intent);
    finish():
```

**override onBackPressed method of the Activity b **

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,A.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```